# Mongoose query compare ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to fetch some documents from my db. In each document, there is a field called 'owner' which is an ObjectId of a user. I want to fetch all of the documents of a specific user. I have the user id and when I'm trying to do something like this:

```
exports.getBoxes = function(req, res) {
    const { user } = res.locals;
    const query = db.Box.find();
    query.where('owner').equals(user._id);
    query.exec(function(err, boxes) {
        console.log(boxes);
    });
}
```

I get an empty array. I saw in my db and there are many boxes that corresponds to this query. What's wrong with it?

**UPDATE**
Here is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamps');

const BoxSchema = new Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  producer: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  cycle: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  owner: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Supplier'
  },
  event: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Event'
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: []
  },
  creditTerms: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Cash', '30 Days', '60 Days', '90 Days', '120 Days']
  },
  bids: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Bid'
  }],
  looking: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
  sold: Boolean,
  paid: Boolean,
  delivered: Boolean,
  sealed: Boolean,
  initialPrice: Number,
  value: Number,
  cts: Number,
  ppc: Number,
  finalPrice: Number
});

BoxSchema.plugin(timestamps);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Box', BoxSchema);
```

And here is an example of documents that I try to fetch:
https://i.gyazo.com/38f2d16d6831b831adb3cc448ef74d01.png

Comment: I suggest as I don't understand how your query bits  new mongodb.ObjectID(user.id)  for _id comparison to _id comparison.  This assumes Box has data and you are getting back a query of course and no idea how it's structured.

Comment: This shoul solve your problem:- 

exports.getBoxes = function(req, res) {
    const { user } = res.locals;
    const query = db.Box.find({"owner " : user._id});
    query.exec(function(err, boxes) {
        console.log(boxes);
    });
}

Comment: @AbhishekSingh It's not working. It still responds with an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys I managed to solve this problem. The problem was that the owner field in the box schema referenced a Supplier object, not a User object. So I solved it like so:

```
const { user } = res.locals;
return db.Supplier.findOne({ userId: user._id })
       .populate('boxes').exec(function(err, supplier) {
            if(err || !supplier) return res.sendStatus(404);

            res.json(supplier.boxes);
        });
```